# Accessing dictionary values in django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I'm trying to access key value pairs from a dictionary in a Django template, but am facing some issues.

The dictionary looks something like this:

```
{datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>): [<Item: do something1>],
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 24, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>): [<Item: dosomething2>,<Item: dosomething3>]}
```

Django template:

```
{% if item_list %}
    <ul>
        {{item_list}}
        {% for key, value in item_list %}
            <h3>{{key}}</h3>
            {% for item in value %}
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.title}}">{{item.title}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No items are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    try:
        item_list = sort_items_by_date()
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'item_list':item_list, 'new_item_form':ItemForm()})
```

When the template is rendered, none of the items from the dictionary show up. I looked up other similar questions here and tried their solutions (e.g. using item_list.date) but it didn't work. I'd really appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: how are you sending the dictionary in the context?

Comment: oops just added it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> {% for key, value in item_list %}
> ```

Iterating over a dictionary yields keys.

```
 {% for key, value in item_list.iteritems %}
```